# How to make your own Enums

Tags: go

Im new in GoLang and im looking for some help. Im working with Windows 10 and Visual Studio Code.

What i want to do is to use `Enums` in my `main.go` file. I make a folder for it named "Enums", and file in it named `SQLQuerys.go` that looks like this:

```
package SqlQuerys

type SqlQuery string

const (

CreateTable SqlQuery = `CREATE TABELE key.users(id int, email text, title text, content text, magic_number int, PRIMARY KEY(id));`

)
```

So it is simple string that i want to pass in function in `main.go` that looks like this (i commented query that works fine):

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    SqlQuerys "golangapi/Enums" //import enums here

    "github.com/gocql/gocql"
)

func main() {
    // connect to the cluster
    cluster := gocql.NewCluster("127.0.0.1")
    cluster.ProtoVersion = 3
    cluster.Keyspace = "key"
    cluster.Consistency = gocql.Quorum
    session, _ := cluster.CreateSession()
    defer session.Close()

    //if err := session.Query(`CREATE TABEL IF NOT EXISTS key.users(id int, email text, title text, content text, magic_number int, PRIMARY KEY(id));`).Exec(); err != nil {
    //  log.Fatal(err)
    //}

    if err := session.Query(SqlQuerys.CreateTable).Exec(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

}
```

How to import one GoLang file to another?

After debug, i get this error:

```
main.go:6:2: cannot find package "golangapi/Enums" in any of:
C:\Go\src\golangapi\Enums (from $GOROOT)
C:\Users\Admin\go\src\golangapi\Enums (from $GOPATH)
exit status 1
```

How to make possible to see another .go file in another? Thanks for any advices

Comment: Please read "How to write Go Code" which explains this in detail. Note that it is _impossible_ to import files. You import packages only. You first error is because you have two declarations of SqlQuery because `CreateTable SqlQuery = "CREATE ..." `  is _not_ valid Go syntax. Refer to the "Tour of Go" for these basics. Regarding the import: Carefully reading the error message tells you where the go tool is looking (and not finding) the package you want to import. And: do _not_ use uppercase file or folder names.

Comment: @Volker that absolutely is valid Go syntax: https://play.golang.org/p/umpmaLqZ7Ie

Comment: Working with another files is pretty simple in C, C++, C#, Python, Java etc but not in Go like i see here.

I just want to keep main as simple as possible, thats why i try to make enums to be calling in functions. SQL querys are long and looks bad in functions. 

my `main.go` is on `/golangapi/main.go` folder. I try to get into: `golangapi/Enums/SQLQuerys.go` in `main.go`. I improve some thing and it looks like i can build `SQLQuerys.go`. but in main, i cant import `import "golangapi/Enums" because IDE deleting it when it starts to compile. I have no idea, why it is so complicated here

Comment: And im doing clearly, what is write in `How to write Go Code`, i just checked it out, so i have no idea why you downvote my question.

Comment: @Adrian You are right. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go is more like *idiomatic* Java. While in Java technically you can mix and match the namespace declarations in files with the directory structure, generally they need to match. In Go, they *must* match in order to work correctly. Your import path (used in an `import` statement) must match either a repo the library can be checked out from, or the path on disk starting from `$GOPATH/src` (which should generally be one and the same). The package name (used in the `package` statement) should match the last part of the path (the name of the directory containing  the file). There is no referencing from one file to another *file*, only from one file to a *package* (just like Java). So, to take your example:

```
$GOPATH
 - src/
   - golangapi/
     - main.go
     - enums/
       - sqlqueries.go
```

main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "golangapi/enums"
    "github.com/gocql/gocql"
)
...
if err := session.Query(enums.CreateTable).Exec(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

sqlqueries.go:

```
package enums

type SqlQuery string

const (

CreateTable SqlQuery = `CREATE TABELE key.users(id int, email text, title text, content text, magic_number int, PRIMARY KEY(id));`

)
```

Comment: I think i see where is a problem in my example. In `Debug Console` i get error, that it cannot find package in any of:

`C:\golangapi\enums (from $GOROOT)` 
`C:\Users\Admin\go\src\golangapi\Enums (from $GOPATH)`

my project directory is something like: 

`D:\project\golangapi...`.

I can not make packages in directories diffrent thatn is set in `PATH` variables on my windows?

Comment: That is changing somewhat with the addition of modules in Go 1.11, but generally speaking, Go expects the source of all Go projects to be within subdirectories of `$GOPATH/src`.

Comment: So the best way is to move my project to `$GOPATH` direcotry?